# Android app doesnt´t work when I signed

Tags: android, debugging, apk, signed

I made an Android app using android Studio. This app have some UI controls and sends some email in background using some Java jars.

The app works OK if I have the mobile connected to the computer but If I create a KeyStore and I do "generate signed apk" the .apk displays the controls and apparently works OK but doesn’t send emails.

I have try "debug" and "release" build types but none of them works.

The interesting thing is that the .apk created in the path

\app\build\outputs\apk named "app-debug-unaligned" **works OK**.

so... What´s happening?  Why I can make working my "signed" app.

what’s is the purpose of \app\build\outputs\apk directory .APKs?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do people in situations like this fail so often to consider that showing their `logcat` output might be essential?

Comment: When I’m debugging the logcat is OK. If I install the signed apk and then connect the mobile to computer the log cat fails in email sending with this text:

09-15 18:23:08.535  21193-21226/? I/Error﹕ a.b.p: smtp
09-15 18:23:08.535  21193-21226/? I/Error﹕ smtp

Comment: I have put more information on Exception catch:

Comment: I have put more information on Exception catch

I/Error﹕ a.b.p: smtp
I/Error﹕ smtp
I/Error﹕ a.b.p: smtp
a.b.p: smtp
at a.b.x.b(Unknown Source)
at a.b.x.a(Unknown Source)
at a.b.x.a(Unknown Source)
at a.b.x.b(Unknown Source)
at a.b.x.a(Unknown Source)
at a.b.ag.b(Unknown Source)
at a.b.ag.a(Unknown Source)
at my.package.b.a(Unknown Source)
at my.package.a.a(Unknown Source)
my.package.a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

Answer (score 0):

I ‘have solve de problem:

in fact, there were 2 problems:

in order to import correctly the JAR files, I have added new module- import .JAR file. It wasn´t enough to copy in Libs and write the dependencies in gradle.

the second thin was to put minify enabled = false in release build type because instead only works on debug.